# Scaling Movieclip according to the input from sensor

Tags: flash, arduino, scaling, sensors

I am new to adobe flash community and new on using the flash language, so pardon me about it.

I am currently trying to send data from the pressure sensor through Arduino and display it on flash.
Don't worry about the sensor and Arduino side of it since I have done the coding and communication part of it to flash, now I am trying to do is when the user press the sensor to have the circle ball [movieclip] to scale and expand the size according to the amount of pressure input from the sensor.

Below is the code I have done so far for the scaling and hopefully is on track, I use the width and height to adjust the size however I received an error that said "call to possibly undefined method CircleGreen".
Any ideas on what to do is greatly appreciate it , I will play around and let you know if I fix the problem.

Thank you

```
var circleGreen = new CircleGreen();

a.addEventListener(ArduinoEvent.ANALOG_DATA, onTickk);

function onTickk(e:ArduinoEvent):void{

  var feetValue:int;
  feetValue = a.getAnalogData(0);  //to get the data from the sensor

  circleGreen.x = -circleGreen.width / 2 + 312;
   circleGreen.y = -circleGreen.height / 2 + 188;

  circleGreen.width = feetValue / 40 ;
  circleGreen.height = feetValue / 40 ;

  addChild(circleGreen);

}
```

Comment: I've changed the variable var circleGreen = new MovieClip();, the error for "possibly undefined method CircleGreen" has disappeared but nothing happens, the circle is not resizing, although there are no error displayed. I assume is my logic of the coding is wrong. I will fiddle around more in the hope of finding solution soon.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var circleGreen = new MovieClip();

addChild(circleGreen);   
//you can hide it with: circleGreen.visible = false;
a.addEventListener(ArduinoEvent.ANALOG_DATA, onTickk);    

function onTickk(e:ArduinoEvent):void{

  var feetValue:int;
  feetValue = a.getAnalogData(0);  //to get the data from the sensor

  circleGreen.x = -circleGreen.width / 2 + 312;
   circleGreen.y = -circleGreen.height / 2 + 188;

  circleGreen.width = feetValue / 40 ;
  circleGreen.height = feetValue / 40 ;
}
```

'onTickk' creates new green circle when is called, so you have to create it first or remove last one

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying, the code is not working, the ball wont resize. I am atm trying a new code where i create the green ball using sprite and resizing it using scaleX and scaleY. Anyway, if i found both solution, will post mine here so anyone who is in my similar situation could help them out.

Comment: NerdJunior12 ...can you pls add this line in onTickk function: trace("onTick - success", feetValue); and look for an output

Comment: Hi there, it trace the output success but I didn't touch the sensor it still trace succes and the output trace goes really fast.

Comment: You have to check Arduino code, also you can try to set static value for feetValue = 20 then 50. Change first line to: var circleGreen:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

Comment: Yeah, I will check the arduino and let you know about it. But one question, the reason why it is not resizing is from the flash side of it? My other code successfully display the average pressure from the sensor, although im using the textfield for that. I want to say thank you so much for your time though!

Comment: i`m not sure, if you have working textField -  trace("onTick - success", feetValue); should output something like "onTick - success 10" - 10 is  feetValue value from Arduino board. Try to "slow down' Arduino output